# Project Symfony 3.4 : release issue on OVH server

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I can't deployed my Symfony 3.4 website on OVH server.

My website works locally, even after clear my cache :

```
php bin/console cache:clear
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I made a lot of researches :
* in my file app.php, I try : $kernel = new AppKernel (‘prod’, true);
* I follow OpenClassroom tutorial : 
https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/3619856-developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony/3626249-deployer-son-site-symfony-en-production

Nothing works !

In my logs (var/logs/prod.log), I have this message :

> [2018-10-12 14:30:59] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "No mapping file found named 'Typesoins.orm.xml' for class >'BeauteBienEtreBundle\Entity\Typesoins'." at /home/beauteboop/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php line 75 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException(code: 0): No mapping file found named 'Typesoins.orm.xml' for class 'BeauteBienEtreBundle\Entity\Typesoins'. at /home/beauteboop/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:75)"} []

I think I have a problem with my entity mapping, but I don't understand why.
You can check my github:

> https://github.com/nicolasberry/beaute-bien-etre.git

What can I do ?… 
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Is the entry point of the site at `/home/beauteboop/www/` ?

Comment: @Cid : _that's right_

Comment: Where did you uploaded the whole site? inside `/home/beauteboop/www/` ? I mean with the src folders and stuff

Comment: @Cid: _yes I did_

Comment: in `/home/beauteboop/www/` there should be the content of the `web` folder. your files should be uploaded to `/home/beauteboop/`

Comment: @Cid: _I already try and it's not the issue. My logs indicate that is a mapping problem : "No mapping file found named 'Typesoins.orm.xml' for class >'BeauteBienEtreBundle\Entity\Typesoins'."_